# Real Time Search in HTML Table Which has Pagination?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a HTML table in my ASP.NET MVC application which is having 10 Rows for one Page with 50 pages with Pagination and sort enabled, for searching  I have added a piece of jquery code which I found out

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

It works fine for the current page, but it doesn't search the whole table ? Could you please help me out for the same ?

Help appreciated , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: It depends how you paginate this table. If this is async data load every time you change page (and should be like that), you'll need server side search, as you don't have all data on the client at the time of searching.

Comment: @komsky thanks for the Idea, appreciated ur help :)